# how to insert null in postgres with php

Tags: php, postgresql, null

I'm trying to insert null into a postgres database with php. Say I have this:

```
<?php
$sql = <<<EOT
insert into
    t1
(c1, c2)
values
($param, 'test')
EOT;
?>
```

I tried setting $param to:

```
$param = null;
$param = '\N';
```

and in each case I got this error:

```
Native message: ERROR:  syntax error at or near ","
```

What do I need to set it to?

Comment: 1. Prepared statements. 2. `NULL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$param = 'null';
```

it should work.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using parameters.

Either with PDO:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(?,?)";
$insertStatement = $pdo->prepare($query);
$insertStatement->execute([null, 'test']);
```

[Execute PHP online](https://phpize.online/s/H4)

of with pgsql functions

```
pg_query_params($dbconn, 'INSERT INTO t1 VALUES($1,$2)', [null, 'test']);
```

Answer (score -1):

The way you deal with null depends on type of the fields and the syntax of the query.
Suppose you write the following query:

```
UPDATE table SET fld_char='$fld_char', fld_int=$fld_int WHERE id=0
```

Then you can set the variables as these:

```
fld_char = null;
fld_int = 'null';
```

You will have fld_int as null and fld_char as empty.

Comment: so you failed to answer how to insert fld_char as null. not to mention that you should NEVER have $fld_char or $fld_int in your query. Learn about **prepared statements**

Comment: if I leave $fld_char or $fld_int in the query which thing is allowed though not recommended, how can I have fld_char NULL?

Comment: You just DON'T have them in the query. Problem solved

Comment: I agree on prepared statements but look at the accepted answer which shows the OP requirement.

Comment: I did look at that bad answer. So what?